# show asterisk(*) sign on a field name in jqgrid form

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid and sorry for my weak English.

Currently I am using jqgrid to show the data in view. I want to show a asterisk(*) sign for a compulsory field in a jqgrid form, I can able to add it by adding `formoptions:{elmprefix:"*"}` to field but it is showing on left hand side of textbox or selectBox due to which this boxes are shifted little bit to right hand side.So this fields and other fields for which asterisk sign is not shown they are not in an align due to which it not looking proper.

So is there any way to show asterisk(*) sign near to field name instead of text-box and text-box should not move to right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding asterisk to form field label manually:

```
{name: 'Columnname', index: 'Columnname', editable: true, 
 editrules: {required: true}, 
 formoptions: {label: 'Columnname *'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

you should use formoptions with rowpos,colpos options. Try and set values for these.

```
   { name: 'Columnname', index: 'Columnname', width: 150, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *',rowpos:1, colpos:2}}
```

You can also use `prefix: "", suffix:""` options.

rowpos  number  determines the row position of the element (again with the text-label) in the form; the count begins from 1

colpos  number  determines the column position of the element (again with thelabel) in the form beginning from 1

Comment: Thanks for reply Alfred, i tried as you suggested but i don't want to show a asterisk(*) after the textbox,Is there any way to show a asterisk(*) on a field-label side instead a textbox side.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to append asterisk **after the label**:

```
$( '.asterisk' ).remove(); //To avoid appending * over and over everytime you open the form
$( '#tr_Name td.CaptionTD' ).append( "<span class='asterisk'>*</span>" );
```

Quite messy but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
label: 'Name',
formoptions: { label: 'Name <b style="color: red;">*</b>' },
name: 'individuo_nome',
width: 100,
editable: true,
...
```